# Game of Life click and drag

Tags: vb.net, conways-game-of-life

I am making the game of life and have encountered a problem I can't solve.

For the game I create a grid of buttons in code and I want to add a handler where when the mouse button is clicked and dragged over any of the buttons it makes the button alive or dead.

But I can't find any handler that will help with this.
This is how I add handlers every time a new button is created:

```
Dim x, y As Integer
'  Start 15 px in from left hand side of form
Dim left As Integer = 0
'  Set the size of the textbox dimensions (height and width)
Dim boxdims As Integer
'  Start 20 px from the top of the form
Dim topgap As Integer = 25
' Number of cells (horCell by VerCell)
Dim right As Integer = 15

If cboCellWorldSize.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
    boxdims = 40
    horCell = (screenWidthRes \ boxdims)
    verCell = (screenHeightRes \ boxdims)
ElseIf cboCellWorldSize.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
    boxdims = 25
    horCell = (screenWidthRes \ boxdims)
    verCell = (screenHeightRes \ boxdims)
ElseIf cboCellWorldSize.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
    boxdims = 15
    horCell = (screenWidthRes \ boxdims)
    verCell = (screenHeightRes \ boxdims)
End If

ReDim cellArray(horCell, verCell)


For x = 0 To horCell  '  Nested loop for rows and cols
    For y = 0 To verCell

        '  Create a new Button
        Dim NextButton As New Button
        '  Set some of its Properties
        With NextButton
            .Left = left
            .Height = boxdims
            .Width = boxdims
            .BackColor = dead
            .Top = topgap + (NextButton.Height * y)
            .FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0

            AddHandler NextButton.MouseEnter, AddressOf Me.btnClick


        End With


        cellArray(x, y) = NextButton
        '  Add this new button to the Form's Controls Collection

        Me.Controls.Add(NextButton)

    Next
    '  Ready to start the next column
    '  Move the left side of the next column of textboxes
    '  over to the right.
    left += boxdims
Next
```

I am currently using a mouseEnter event but it does not suite the game properly

Comment: Why the drag?  Left click on a dead button to make it alive.  Left click on an alive button to make it dead.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I believe it's because he wants cells to become dead / alive as he moves his clicked mouse over his cells.

Comment: @Alex: I believe so as well.  Unfortunately, most people can't draw that accurately with a mouse.

Comment: Implement actual drag/drop with your button via [DoDragDrop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop.aspx) and handle the DragEnter() event for all your buttons.  You'll need to set the AllowDrop() property for all the buttons to true.